# operations on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that the universe U is the set of all lower case letters alphabetically up to k, i.e.

```
 U = {a, b, c, . . . , k}. 

P = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
Q = {b, c, d}
R = {c, d, e, f, g}
S = {f, g}
T = {d}
```

State the result of the following operations:

```
(a) P ∩ Q
(b) P ∪ R
(c) Q∪R∪S
(d) Q ∩ R
(e) Q ∩ S
(f) (R ∩ S) ∪ (Q ∩ T)
(g) P – R’ 
(h) (R – P)’ 
(i) Q x S 
(j) (T x R) ∩ (Q x S)
```

I got the following

```
(a) {b, c, d}
(b) {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
(c) {b, c, d, e, f, g}
(d) {c, d}
(e) {Ø}
(f) {f, g, d}
(g) {a,b}
(h) {h, i, j, k}
(i) {<b,f>, <b,g>, <c,f>, <c,g>, <d,f>, <d,g>}
(j) {<d,f>, <d,g>}
```

Not sure about (g) and (h)

Comment: Does the quote at the end of (g) and (h) mean complement in U ? The other answers look good.

Comment: What is the meaning of your prime here?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that $R'$ is everything not in $R$.  So,
$$
R'=\{a,b,h,i,j,k\}.
$$
Then $P-R'$ is everything in $P$ that is not in $R'$.  Thus
$$
P-R'=\{c,d,e,f,g\}.
$$
Can you do the same for $(h)$?

Answer (score 0):

$(P - R') = (\text{P }  \cap \text{ R}) = \{\text{c, d, e, f, g}\}$
$(\text{ R } - \text{ P })' = \{a, b\}' = \{c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k\}$

Answer (score 0):

$U = \{a, b, c, . . . , k\}$.

$R'=U-R=\{a, b, c, . . . , k\}-\{c, d, e, f, g\}=\{a,b,h,i,j,k\}$

**Remove out the common elements.**
$P-R'=\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g\}-\{a,b,h,i,j,k\}=\{c,d,e,f,g,\}$

$(R – P)’=U-(R-P)$
$R-P=\{c, d, e, f, g\}-\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g\}=\{ \}.$ Null set

$(R-P)'=U$

Comment: @user88595Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have that $R\subset P$ this implies that $R-P = \emptyset $ then its complement is $U$. The universe.

In similar way, you have that $R'=\{a,b,h,i,j,k\}$ then $P-R'=\{c,d,e,f,g\}$.